# android alarmmanager reset

Tags: android, alarmmanager, reset

My application uses below code to set Alaram to execute service on "Daily" basis.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SchedulerEventReceiver.class); // explicit// intent

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
        PendingIntent intentExecuted = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, new Random().nextInt(), i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intentExecuted);
```

`adb shell dumpsys alarm` shows me proper details. like it is scheduled to run daily. However when i install .apk to my phone, it is executing repeatedly. it doesnt wait for a day to execute.

I dont know how to reset alarm set in my phone. i uninstalled the app and newly installed app, but it didn't work. can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: you need to trigger alarm when app installed and phone restart

Answer (score 1):

i have used this and this is working fine for me. i have used this alarm to trigger after 18 days. and then again after 18 days and so on:

```
long time = 1555200000L; //18 days = 18*24*60*60*1000 = 1555200000L
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, tag, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+time, time, pi);
```

Comment: with this code alarm never wakes up to execute task.private static final int EXEC_INTERVAL = 24*60*60*1000;AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);                                   Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SchedulerEventReceiver.class);                                            PendingIntent intentExecuted = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, new Random().nextInt(), i,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+EXEC_INTERVAL, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intentExecuted);

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are telling it to go off 20 seconds into the minute

```
now.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
```

You need to add the hour of the day and possible minute

```
 now.add(Calendar.HOUR, 12) //set your hour here. noon right now
```

or

```
now.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12)
```

[Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#SECOND)

Comment: But i am saying to wakeup at AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY. would that be sufficient or i need something else?

Comment: I did not see that `param`, sorry. It should but I will check into it before deleting. I'm thinking it might not know when those 20 seconds should be so I would try adding an hour and see if it works

Comment: i will do that but my question is, why it is behaving differently in emulator. As per logic in my app, once alarm start, i am sending notification. I dont see any notification in Emulator. However i can see notification appear frequently in my phone.